# Implementing WrapBootstrap theme into Rails App

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just bought a wrapbootstrap theme and am trying to insert it into my rails application.  Some of the css like the padding, navbar, glyphicons, and most of the javascripts are not functioning correctly.  I copied all the stylesheets and javascripts into the assets/stylesheets and assets/javascripts respectively.  Any idea how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a nice collection of themes , indeed . You should first open your `css` files and replace all calls to `../img/` dir with plain `images/` to make pipeline find the graphic elements of the theme . That's the easy part .

For using the glyphs you should create a new dir under assets , for example `fonts` . Then copy the glyphs images there and expand the usable assets in `application.rb` file , like this :

```
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

After that , you should rename your `font-awesome.css` to `font-awesome.css.scss.erb` and change the `@font-face` declaration in it like this :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%>');
src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')%>') format('eot'), url('<%=    asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff')%>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf')%>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')%>') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

If I've missed some small part, it is because of the Saturday night red wine ... Do not hessitate to ask for more details  .